# setTimeout not working before animation runs

Tags: javascript

The `setTimeout` function is not delaying the start of the simple animation i have created.

```js
var counter = document.getElementById("counter"); 

  function countUp() {
 if(parseFloat(counter.innerHTML) < 100) {
  counter.innerHTML = parseFloat(counter.innerHTML) + 1;    
     }
 }

setTimeout(countUp, 3000);
var counterId = setInterval(countUp, 125);
```

```html
<span id="counter">0</span>
```

Comment: You're setting the script to run once after 3000 milliseconds, and then the very next line sets it to run every 125 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're expecting--you set `countUp` to run after three seconds, then you immediately tell it to run every 125 milliseconds.

If you want it to *delay* starting up for three seconds, then give `setTimeout` a function that sets the interval, roughly:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  setInterval(countUp, 125);
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout doesn't block. All it does is setting a timeout, then calling the function once after the timeout expires. That means that both, the timeout and the interval will be called immediately after page load. I'd simply set a timeout once, then recall it within the function

```js
var counter = document.getElementById("counter");

function countUp() {
  if (parseFloat(counter.innerHTML) < 100) {
    counter.innerHTML = parseFloat(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
    setTimeout(countUp, 125);
  }
}

setTimeout(countUp, 3000);
```

```html
<span id="counter">0</span>
```

This will also prevent your interval from running to infinity - you only don't notice it because there are no further changes made to the innerHTML once it reaches 100 - the function though will still be called every 125 ms

Answer (score -1):

You should review concepts such as **run to completion** and the operation of **Event Loop**.

The code is badly constructed.

setTimeout if it is executed, but first we see the setInterval execution that changes the values contained in the span tag.

SetTimeout function param is placed in a queue and after 3 seconds it reaches the increment, but due to the speed of the counter update, you cannot see its effect or execution.

I have modified the code to show the effect of SetTimeout.

Please note that Javascript has only one execution thread and if execution is blocked, the browser will also be blocked.

A bad way to block the execution is to use a while loop that runs until the counter passes the 3 seconds.
Uncomment the **bad way code** to see it.
[SetTimeout in action](https://jsfiddle.net/u0L82px4/10/)

```
var counter = document.getElementById("counter");   

  function countUp() {
    if(parseFloat(counter.innerHTML) < 100) {
  counter.innerHTML = parseFloat(counter.innerHTML) + 1;       
     }
    }

  function countUpZero() {          
  //to see SetTimeout function param in execution
    if(parseFloat(counter.innerHTML) < 100) {
  counter.innerHTML = parseFloat(counter.innerHTML) + 1000;    
     }
  //end
    }
    //bad way to get delay
    /*
    var timestamp  = Date.now()+3000;
    while (Date.now() < timestamp);
    */
    //end bad way

setTimeout(countUpZero, 3000);    

var counterId = setInterval(countUp, 125);
```